# backbone collection fetch() returns one record only

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to fetch list of objects from server, the collection accepts the first record and ignores the rest.

the response from the server is of type `application/json`

```
 [{"id":1,"name":"A"}, 
  {"id":2,"name":"B"}, 
  {"id":3,"name":"C"}]
```

in client side,

```
 var collection = new Backbone.Collection;
 collection.url = 'url_to_the_resource';

 collection.fetch();
 console.log( collection.toJSON());
```

the output is

```
 [{"id":1,"name":"A"}]
```

**edit**

I call log when the collection is ready, i.e. after the asynchronous call is complete as follows:

```
collection.fetch().done( function() {
  console.log( collection.toJSON() );
});
```

and still getting one record. I have also checked backbone.js source code, and found the following at line `682`

```
    // If a duplicate is found, prevent it from being added and
    // optionally merge it into the existing model.
    if (existing = this.get(model)) {
```

and added a logging right after that line, and found that backbone merges all models, why?

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess. If you can provide collection code it would be great.

1. Be sure model [idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) (if it is overridden) is unique.
2. Check your collection `parse` method if it is overridden. It should return the array of objects.
3. Try to play with `add`, `remove`, `merge`
   http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set.

Comment: the code I use to fetch is what you see above, which means I change nothing except the url. I even suspected that the server sends a malformed json, and created a static json file and pointed the collection url to it. but still getting only the first record.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason,

it was because I have attached an event on the model prototype

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.on('request',function(model, xhr, options){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is the Override issue,
even each record of the original JSON data is totally different at all.

---

Revoke [***idAttribute***](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) property in Model or revoke [***modelId***](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-modelId) method in Collection may help.

---

You could use `.findWhere({_id: pkId})` instead of `.get(pkId)`